# How come my json is returning different data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Not sure why this is happening but i am sure it is probably causing the problems i am running into. when i type http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?1 in the url bar of my browser i get my json data but without my "id" attribute returned in the window of the browser. but if i place this url http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?5 in the url browser bar it will be fine and returns the correct json in the projects.js file. I have no idea why it has a problem with 1-4 but not 5 and up.
I am comparing the last segments in the url bar if you have not figured it out.

The url's with the last segments of a value between 0 and 4 return what was projects.js file but an old version of it.This is really weird I don't even know how it could do that.+

Bad json being returned and script does not work:

```
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?0
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?1
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?2
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?3
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?4
```

Good json being return:

```
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?5
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?6
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?7
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?8
http://travismichael.net/travis/js/projects.js?9
```

and up
I have no idea how this is happening. here is my json:

```
    {
      "projects":[
          {
            "id":"0",
            "title":"Heller Recipes", 
            "description":"This web applications was developed to keep track of my dads recipes and make them easily accesible.He is now able to check each user and make a dinner based on what everybody likes or in some cases dont like. ",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-app",
            "largePic":"img/projects/heller-recipes/thumb.jpg", 
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },  
        {
            "id":"1",
            "title":"3D Animation", 
            "description":"Created using 4D Cinema Max, a 3d anitmation program that allows you to create realistic renderings and animations.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"3d",
            "largePic":"img/projects/4dmax.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        }, 
        {
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Body by Design", 
            "description":"This web applications was developed to keep track of my dads recipes and make them easily accesible.He is now able to check each user and make a dinner based on what everybody likes or in some cases dont like.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"wordpress",
            "largePic":"img/projects/bbd.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        }, 
        {
            "id":"3",
            "title":"Team Bootcamp", 
            "description":"Tshirt Design for Lifetime Fitness",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"illustration",
            "largePic":"img/projects/bootcamp.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"4",
            "title":"Digital Painting", 
            "description":"Digital Painting",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"illustration",
            "largePic":"img/projects/digitalpaint.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"5",
            "title":"Alien Flash Animation", 
            "description":"Quick flash animation of a abduction from aliens",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"animation",
            "largePic":"img/projects/flashalien.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"6",
            "title":"InHealth CDS", 
            "description":"Web site made for inhealth cds.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-design",
            "largePic":"img/projects/inhealthcds.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"7",
            "title":"InHealth Product Video", 
            "description":"",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-design",
            "largePic":"img/projects/inhealthvideo.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"8",
            "title":"Single Web Page App", 
            "description":"Single web page application made for marketing the sales of longrange treatment of cattle to show the difference between users company and the competitors treatment product.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-app",
            "largePic":"img/projects/longrange.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"9",
            "title":"Single Web Page App", 
            "description":"Single web page application made for marketing the sales of preventive treatment for dogs to show the difference between users company and the competitors treatment product.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-app",
            "largePic":"img/projects/nexgard.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"10",
            "title":"Pinup Illustration", 
            "description":"2d illustration of a war pinup girl using graphite pencils.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"illustration",
            "largePic":"img/projects/pinup.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"11",
            "title":"Responsive Web Design", 
            "description":"The ability to design web apps using mobile first concepts. A quick representation of a starbucks strore app using responsive design.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-design",
            "largePic":"img/projects/rwd.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"12",
            "title":"Web Agency Site Developement", 
            "description":"An interactive site that displays the agencies character and style using animations and a style guide that meshes with the branding and image of the company.",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"web-design",
            "largePic":"img/projects/satori.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        },
        {
            "id":"13",
            "title":"Tshirt-Design for Fitness club", 
            "description":"Tshirt design made for a Crossfit fitness club called NoQuarter",
            "technologiesUsed":"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0",
            "projectLink":"http://www.google.com",
            "genre":"illustration",
            "largePic":"img/projects/tshirtdesign.jpg",
            "desktopImg":"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",
            "desktopMobile":"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"
        }
    ]


}
```

Comment: We would need to see some server code to debug the server.  But fwiw, when i test the different urls, i get the same JSON in response for ...?1 as for ...?5

Comment: I figured it out. the json must of been chached cause when hit went to the bad urls and then refreshed them the correct json shows

Comment: Not sure why it does this or how to prevent it. any ideas?

Comment: use a timestamp in search string as cachebuster. If using jQuery ajax that's what it does

Comment: Sorry, not exactly sure what that means. could you provide an example?

Comment: read `cache` section http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Generally easiest while developing to turn off browser caching